# Is fiction an acceptable notable source?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, notability

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Random claims from fantasy stories and movies](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1148/random-claims-from-fantasy-stories-and-movies)

We've had a couple of questions recently that source their "notability" from appearance in fiction.

- [Do elephants like to get drunk?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/3523/6236)
- [Did Americans coin the phrase "to make money"?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/10894/6236)

The current [FAQ question](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/864/6236) doesn't really cover this.

So, should we allow questions whose notability derives from an appearance in fiction?

Answer (score 1):

No, we shouldn't allow questions that derive their notability from fiction.

The set of possible claims is immense, and many are nonsensical. If a claim were believable enough, and enough people mistook it for reality, then there would be notable reproductions of it outside the work of fiction itself.

Comment: Agreed: however, it's also worth noting that many notable claims also appear in fiction; therefore, the mere appearance in movies of fiction should not be taken as evidence of the lack of notability.

Comment: For instance, the elephants get drunk question is a "fact" I personally heard from people who lived in South Africa.  They were disappointed when I corrected them based on this site, but also felt enlightened.