# Do rhetoric and hyperbole qualify as "notable claims?"

Tags: discussion, notability

I've been curious about [this question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/31521/29604).  The claims it quotes were made by persons during the course of political speech-making, and intended to illicit responses from those gathered to listen.  In other words, the claims are mere hyperbole.

Taken to the extreme, if a famous baker speaks at a pro-Chocolate Cake rally, and says "People who don't like Chocolate Cake must be evil!" does that make it a "notable claim" for purposes of this site.

Don't get me wrong, I like the question and the answers it has generated.  It just struck me as unusual.

Answer (score 3):

We have two general principles that apply here. They may be conflicting, which is interesting!

The first principle is that we want to tackle claims that many people believe. (We use commonly repeated, or made by a notable person as a proxy for this.) If everyone (or even everyone but the OP) understands it to be a joke, it isn't notable. However, if many people are confused by it, and believe it is true, we should be willing to tackle it.

The second principle, derived from questions about [claims in movies](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1148/random-claims-from-fantasy-stories-and-movies) is that we only want to deal with propositions that the "claimant" is seriously claiming. If the author doesn't expect people to believe the claim is true outside of the fictional universe they have created, we don't want to be bogged down answering it.

I figure the first principle outweighs the second. If people believe it in, despite the author never intending it to be taken seriously, it is worth addressing. [Alexandria's Genesis](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/10038/does-alexandrias-genesis-exist) is a good example of this.

*[Full disclosure: I am strong advocate of chocolate cake, although I have never had been paid by Big Cake to promote it.]*