# How to cite a claim made in a non-public domain movie?

Tags: discussion

I heard a statement that I wanted to ask the site about.  However, I heard the claim in a movie, and therefore I cannot link to the scene in question (due to copyright issues, etc).

Would an honest transcript of the scene in question and a timestamp be sufficient sourcing of the claim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, but clearly not always, a scene will be available on media sharing sites under fair use exemptions. A transcript should also be fine, although in many cases it might not be sufficient as some claims might have a visual component.

Keep in mind though that [we don't generally allow movies as source of claims](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1148/random-claims-from-fantasy-stories-and-movies?rq=1) because movies are fiction, which is clearly a big disclaimer. We allow claims presented as real e.g. in a honest documentary (i.e. not mockumentaries).

Comment: I understand not allowing movies as the source of a claim.  However, this movie in question, while not a documentary, goes out of its way to be as factually accurate as possible.  There isn't a visual component to the conversation (and it's mostly a monologue anyway) and the claim in question is a testable claim about the US Economy.